# Exceeded rate limits: too many table update operations for this table in Cloud Function while uploading the data from pubsub topic to BQ

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

Let me explain the use case which I am trying to solve

1. I am getting data to the pubsub topic on daily basis in google cloud
2. I have a written a cloud function with pubsub as a trigger type to trigger and execute the
   script inside the cloud function when ever the topic receives the data
3. The function will trigger and uploads the data to Bigquery tables
4. Right now I kept the memory of the function as 256mb and max instances to 100
5. On daily basis I receive very small amount of data like 16 messages to pubsub topic
6. Even the data is small I observed the cloud function is encountering the following error "too
   many table update operations for this table" and I am missing some data
7. I have retry option which I can use but don't want the cloud function to return any errors, Is
   there any workaround for this
8. sharing the sample code below [image]

Comment: Is your question how to resolve the error?  Also is the CF an event based trigger based, if so can it be a batch?

Comment: Yes my question is how to resolve the error. I can't be a batch because the data is coming from pubsub.

Comment: how many times the same file (the data is taken from a message content) is loaded into a BQ table? - I mean - do you have many invocations of the cloud function from a given message?

Comment: No as I said I am getting 16 messages per day per table, I need to upload those 16 messages to the BQ table. There is no repeated invocations per same message

Comment: The reason I ask is because you are using the batch api and not the streaming api.  Which comes with limitations, https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#load_jobs also https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#standard_tables . You are likely hitting one of the defined quotas either the volume in a given time period or the per day  limit.

Comment: Do you have other jobs that update the same tables?

Comment: No I don't have.

Comment: As said my @DanielZagales, it appears that you are hitting one of those quotas. This [Github issue](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigquery-sqlalchemy/issues/34) also suggests the same that if you are appending rows one at a time as in your case, it is advised to use the Streaming API.

Comment: Hi @KrishanuSengupta if I use streaming api in this use case there wont be such issues. And the quotas will also apply for streaming inserts as well right?

Comment: Streaming Inserts have a different set of quotas in terms of maximum bytes per second. Since you have small sized rows, it should not hit this quota. Load job quotas are different and they don't apply to streaming inserts.

Comment: Did it work for you ?

Comment: @KrishanuSengupta I am aware of streaming inserts, The only thing I am thinking about is the pricing part of it. Otherwise I can use streaming inserts inside my code

Comment: Consider accepting/upvoting the answer if you find it helpful. Otherwise, please let me know If I can improve anything.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your code is exceeding the [maximum rate](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#standard_tables) of table metadata update operations per table which is 5 operations per 10 seconds. So it appears that all your Cloud Pub/Sub messages are coming at the same time (or near the same time). You can follow either of the following solutions for the same:

1. As suggested in the comments, you can use Streaming inserts. As this limit does not apply to Streaming Inserts.
2. You can insert a delay in your code for providing time between successive metadata updates. In this case I passed a timeout of 30 seconds to the `result` for the same. This worked for me.

I tried the second method. I published 19 messages from my publisher code at the same time. I got the same error message as yours (when executing without timeout).

[image]

But after Inserting the timeout the execution was successful. (Timeout value can be reduced further as per the requirement)

**Complete Code:**

```
import base64
from google.cloud import bigquery
import json
import io


def hello_pubsub(event, context):
   """Triggered from a message on a Cloud Pub/Sub topic.
   Args:
        event (dict): Event payload.
        context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata for the event.
   """
   client = bigquery.Client()
   pubsub_message = base64.b64decode(event['data']).decode('utf-8')
   print(pubsub_message)
   message = json.loads(pubsub_message)
   result = json.dumps(message)
   source_file = io.StringIO(result)
   table_id="ProjectID.DatasetID.TableName"

   job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
    autodetect=True,
    write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
    source_format=bigquery.SourceFormat.NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON,
    )
   job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_id, job_config=job_config)
   job.result(timeout=30)  #passing a timeout in the function call
```

**Output :** (All 19 rows were inserted, I did not notice any loss of data)

[image]